# How to prevent IntelliJ from forgetting settings on computer crash?

Tags: intellij-idea, crash

I had this 2 times already: computer hangs on project run/compile and after reboot I have numerous setting lost in IntelliJ.

Can't it save them on disk in reliable manner?

Answer (score 0):

Select file from toolbar and then select export settings. After something happens to them you can just import them back.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Settings are auto-saved on various occasions, for example when losing focus, or clicking `Ctrl+S` - Save All.